# How to ensure upload is completed before processing image

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to upload an image file and then process it once it has completed uploading.  How do I ensure that the upload has completed before starting the processing?  My sample code is below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (EmployeeForCreation.Photo != null)
        {
            var arrivalsFolder = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", "arrivals");
            var filePath = Path.Combine(arrivalsFolder, EmployeeForCreation.Photo.FileName);

            await EmployeeForCreation.Photo.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));

            //How to ensure that previous procedure has been completed before this procedure starts
            ProcessImage(filePath, height: 100);
        }
        return RedirectToPage("./Details");
    }
    return Page();
}

public void ProcessImage(string filePath, int height)
{
    string rootDirectoryPath = new DirectoryInfo(filePath).Parent.Parent.FullName;
    var processingPathDirectory = Path.Combine(rootDirectoryPath, Constants.PROCESSING_FOLDER);

    using (Image<Rgba32> image = Image.Load(filePath))
    {
        image.Mutate(x => x
             .Resize(image.Width / 2, image.Height / 2)
             .Grayscale());

        image.Save("processingPathDirectory/fb.png"); // Automatic encoder selected based on extension.
    }
}
```

I'd like to do this without making an ajax call if possible.

I get the following error at run time

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Roger\Documents\ScratchPad\src\Web\wwwroot\images\arrivals\test.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: The await wont move forward till all the data is copied. So I am a little confused about what it is you are asking

Comment: Yes, I am too - I get the following error when I run this:

Comment: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Roger\Documents\ScratchPad\src\Web\wwwroot\images\arrivals\test.jpg' because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is locked because you did not close the previous stream used to create the file.

Make sure to dispose of the previous stream to make sure all data is written to it and the file released.

You can do this by wrapping the stream in a `using` statement.

```
//...

using(var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create)) {
    await EmployeeForCreation.Photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
}

ProcessImage(filePath, height: 100);

//...
```